# Openshift deploy with additional Maven command line options

Tags: maven, openshift

I have a Tomcat7 application hosted on Openshift.
I know that `git push` will result in a deploy. Also, `ctl_app deploy` or `rhc app deploy` will result in a deploy too.

But I want to specify in the maven build the `-U` command line option. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to execute a mvn build directly by doing the following:

1. ssh into your application:
   `rhc ssh <appname>`
2. cd into your app dir:
   `cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR`
3. Execute mvn commands

Example:

```
$mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jbossas 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom (7 KB at 13.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/19/maven-plugins-19.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/19/maven-plugins-19.pom (11 KB at 325.7 KB/sec)
```